# Query to get employees list with whose experience is multiple of 5

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where I want to find the list of employees whose years of experience is multiple of 5, i.e whose experience is above 5 years, above 10 years, above 15 years etc. Employees who crossed 6 years, list should not display, It should display only employee experience with 5,10,15 years.and so on.

table columns
employee id, name, dob, join date.

Can Please anyone help me to get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the difference between todays date and the `join_date` in years and take all those having a multiple of 5 using the modulo operator

```
select *
from employees
where timestampdiff(YEAR, join_date, now()) % 5 = 0
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc8032/1)

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, I have applied the same query, but its showing employees list with joining date of 2020, 2021.
It should show employees with joining date from 2016

Comment: I switched the dates. Try again please

Comment: I found the solution,

select * from employees where floor(datediff(now(),join date)/365) IN(5,10,15,20)
But above i am hardcoding the years

Comment: My query works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc8032/1

Comment: Hie juergen, I want one more result in the above query, I want to get the date ie(yyyy-mm-dd) i.e I want to add 5,10,15 years to the joining date, after dividing it with 5,10,15.years.
Can you please tell me how to achieve it